# Eclipse Luna in fedora Os

Tags: eclipse

Hi I am using eclipse luna in fedora Os. I want to change my redo action key binding from ctrl + shift + z to ctrl + y. So how to do it. i have tried to change it from windows preference menu but no got any result. I can't able to change there.

Answer (score 0):

Change it in `Windows > Preferences > General > Keys`

[image]